# Is there any way to get char by auto type deduction using decimal ASCII Code?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

For example 'a' has ASCII code 97 and we could use

```
char ch = 'a';
```

or

```
char ch = 97;
```

With *auto* we could write

```
auto ch = 'a';
```

for the first case, but how to get char variable by numerical ascii code during deduction?

This doesn't work for me:

```
auto ch = '\97';
```

Comment: Note: `'a'` doesn't mean ASCII code 97. The compiler transcodes literal characters from the `-fsource-charset` to `-fexec-charset` (`/source-charset` to `/execution-charset`). Here, "charset" means character encoding.  The code author, program builder and program user should all be on the same page about character encodings. Often the author attempts to write "portable code" that would work correctly no matter which system the code is built for. Many systems use the UTF-8 character encoding of the Unicode character set throughout.

Comment: sounds strange to simultaneously want a specific type and auto

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have to use octal or hex value for escape sequence

```
auto ch  = '\141';
auto ch2 = '\x61';
```

For more info https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

If you want to use decimal values, you have two options:

1. Cast to char

   ```
   auto ch = static_cast<char>(97);
   ```
2. User-defined literals

   ```
   char operator "" _ch(unsigned long num)
   {
        return static_cast<char>(num);
   }
   //...
   auto ch = 97_ch;
   ```

Comment: Indeed. The cause of the OP's problem is the fact that `'\97'` is invalid octal.

Answer (score 20):

There's no decimal escape, but you can use hexadecimal: `'\x61'`, or octal, `'\141'`.
If you really need decimal, you need to cast; `char{97}`.

Answer (score 8):

There is no integral literal that specifies a `char`. You have to explicitly name the type, e.g.

```
auto ch = char{97};
```

Comment: But if the OP had used a hex integer, then `'\0x61'` would work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Cast an [integral literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) to `char`:

```
auto ch = static_cast<char>(97);
```

Comment: The point is not to write *char* or any big construction, when I use *auto*.